# How to use Riemann sum in the equation of the multifractional Brownian motion to estimate the underlying standard Brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I'm studying the [paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01399570/document) *Estimation of time-dependent Hurst exponents with variational smoothing and application to forecasting foreign exchange rates* in which the author presents the following definition of the multifractional Brownian motion (mBm) (section 2.1 page 4)

$$\tag1
\begin{align*}
X(t) = \frac{\sigma\sqrt{\Gamma(2H(t)+1)\sin(H(t)\pi)}}{\Gamma(H(t)+1/2)} \Bigg( &\int_{-\infty}^0 ((t-s)^{H(t)-1/2}-(-s)^{H(t)-1/2}) dW(s) + {} \\
&+ \int_0^t (t-s)^{H(t)-1/2} dW(s) \Bigg),
\end{align*}
$$

with $H$ Hurst function, $\sigma$ volatility, $W$ standard Brownian motion.
Then in section 5.1, at the step 4 of a simulation procedure (page 15), the author presents this equation to estimate $W$, saying that it is derived from the definition of the mBm

$$\tag2
W(s\delta) = W((s-1)\delta) + (X(s\delta) - X(t\delta))\Pi(s\delta) - \mathbb1_{s>t} \sum_{\color{red}{u=t}}^{s-1} [W(u\delta)-W((u-1)\delta)](s-u+1)^{H(s\delta)-1/2}, \\
\text{where}\quad \Pi(s\delta) = \frac{\Gamma(H(s\delta)+1/2}{\sigma \delta^{H(s\delta)-1/2} \sqrt{\Gamma(2H(s\delta)+1)\sin(H(s\delta)\pi)}}, \\
%\sigma = \frac1\tau \sqrt\frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{s=t}^{t+\tau-1} \frac{|X(s\delta)-X((s-1)\delta)|}{\delta^{H(s\delta)}}, \\
\delta = 1/(\tau-1) \text{ is the time step}, \\
\tau \text{ is a positive integer.}
$$

I did the computations to obtain $(2)$ from $(1)$, but there is a small detail which I don't understand, why is $u=t$ the lower bound of summation in equation $(2)$?

First of all, in order to run the simulation procedure, the equations are discretized introducing the time step $\delta$, and everything is defined for the equispaced times $0, \delta, 2\delta, ..., T\delta$, with $T$ final time. The procedure requires to compute $X((t+\tau)\delta)$ for every $t\in\{0,...,T-\tau\}$ using the values of $W(s\delta)$ for $s\in\{t,...,t+\tau-1\}$, where $\tau < T$ is a positive integer of our choice.

So I guess we should start by discretizing equation $(1)$, using the same notation as in equation $(2)$, i.e. use $s$ instead of $t$ and $u$ instead of $s$. Notice that since $t \ge 0$ then the first integral in equation $(1)$ vanishes. Moreover, moving the fraction from right to left we obtain

$$
\frac{\Gamma(H(s\delta)+1/2)}{\sigma\sqrt{\Gamma(2H(s\delta)+1)\sin(H(s\delta)\pi)}} X(s\delta) = \int_0^s ((s-u)\delta)^{H(s\delta)-1/2} dW(u\delta).
$$

Now, quoting the paper: "at the origin $t$ of the time interval the mBm should be $0$, we translate $X$ by $X(t\delta)$", so we write

$$
\frac{\Gamma(H(s\delta)+1/2)}{\sigma\sqrt{\Gamma(2H(s\delta)+1)\sin(H(s\delta)\pi)}} (X(s\delta)-X(t\delta)) = \int_0^s ((s-u)\delta)^{H(s\delta)-1/2} dW(u\delta).
$$

The integral can be approximated using Riemann sum: let $\pi_n = \{u_0,..,u_n\}$, with $0=u_0<...<u_n=s$, be a partition of the time interval $[0,s]$, with $|\pi_n|=\max\{u_i-u_{i-1}:i=1,...,n\}$, then

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^s ((s-u)\delta)^{H(s\delta)-1/2} dW(u\delta) &= \lim_{|\pi_n| \to 0}\ \sum_{i=1}^n\ ((s-u_{i-1})\delta)^{H(s\delta)-1/2}(W(u_i\delta)-W(u_{i-1}\delta)) \\
&\approx \sum_{i=1}^n\ ((s-u_{i-1})\color{red}{\delta})^{H(s\delta)-1/2}(W(u_i\delta)-W(u_{i-1}\delta)).
\end{align*}
$$

Notice that since the red term does not depend on $i$, we can move it on the other side, hence obtaining the formula of $\Pi(s\delta)$ (see above)

$$\tag3
\Pi(s\delta) (X(s\delta)-X(t\delta)) = \sum_{i=1}^n\ (s-u_{i-1})^{H(s\delta)-1/2}(W(u_i\delta)-W(u_{i-1}\delta)).
$$

Now consider equation (2), notice that $(s-u+1)$ is equal to $1$ when $u=s$, so we can add the term $W(s\delta) - W((s-1)\delta)$ into the series on the right hand side. By doing so we have to increase the upper bound of summation by $1$ (from $s-1$ to $s$), hence obtaining

$$\tag4
\sum_{u=t}^\color{red}s [W(u\delta)-W((u-1)\delta)](s-u+1)^{H(s\delta)-1/2},
$$

but how can we obtain this series starting from the series on the right hand side of $(3)$ ? I do agree that since $u_n = s$, then the upper bound of summation in $(4)$ must be $u = s$, but since $u_0=0$ why is the lower bound of summation equal to $u=t$? Shouldn't it be $u=u_1=u_0+1=1$?